# Convert factor values to POSIXct with dmy_hms turns half of the values to NA

Tags: r, na, posixct

My aim is to concatenate the date and time column, both factor values, in my data set to one column of the structure POSIXct. The columns look like this:

> ```
>   Date      Time
> ```
>
> 1      11.05.2016 09:45:00
>
> 2      11.05.2016  09:46:00
>
> 3      11.05.2016  09:47:00
>
> 4      11.05.2016  09:49:00

What I tried first was:

```
D1 = paste(D$Date, D$Time) 

Date_Time = as.POSIXct(D1, format='%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S')

as.data.frame(Date_Time)
```

What I get is Na values in each row. I could not find out why, so I tried a different method using the lubridate package:

```
Date_Time = mdy_hms(D1,tz="")

Date_Time = as.data.frame(Date_Time)
```

The console interface returns: "134021 failed to parse", which is about half of my data. The converted data is almost always the dates and times of the first two weeks of a month. My question is, why does it convert half of the values to NA's and how can I solve that problem? And why does it not work at all with the as.POSIXct command?

Thanks.

Comment: Your `paste()` is likely wrong -- do `paste(as.character(...), as.character(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Y` instead of `y` for 4 digit years:

```
Date_Time = as.POSIXct(D1, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: That's it. I can't believe it but it works now. I must have made the same mistake over and over again when I rewrote the code. Thank you very much for your quick response.

Comment: @CarolusFridericus You are welcome. Since you are new to SO, accept 
 the answer when you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After `paste` function use this if you need time as well

`Date_Time<- strptime(Date, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")`